Chart.js Streaming Plugin in FilamentPHP: Error: "realtime" is not a registered scale
I'm trying to integrate the chartjs-plugin-streaming plugin with Chart.js in a Laravel project using FilamentPHP for real-time data visualization. My goal is to use the realtime scale provided by chartjs-plugin-streaming in a Filament ChartWidget, but the scale isn’t recognized, and I'm not seeing any streaming updates.
Here’s a summary of my setup and what I’ve tried so far:

Installed the streaming plugin: npm install chartjs-plugin-streaming --save

Configured filament-chart-js-plugins.js: resources/js/filament-chart-js-plugins.js:


import ChartPluginZoom from 'chartjs-plugin-zoom';
import ChartPluginStreaming from 'chartjs-plugin-streaming';

window.filamentChartJsPlugins ??= [];
window.filamentChartJsPlugins.push(ChartPluginZoom);
window.filamentChartJsPlugins.push(ChartPluginStreaming);


Updated vite.config.js to include filament-chart-js-plugins.js

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/css/filament/admin/theme.css',
                'resources/js/filament-chart-js-plugins.js', // Ensuring the plugins file is built
            ],
        }),
    ],
});


Registered the custom asset in Filament: AppServiceProvider.php

FilamentAsset::register([
    Js::make('chart-js-plugins', Vite::asset('resources/js/filament-chart-js-plugins.js'))->module(),
]);


Ran commands:

npm run build
php artisan filament:assets

After performing all the above steps, the plugin doesn’t seem to work correctly: Error: "realtime" is not a registered scale.
If I disable the Streaming Plugin, the Zoom Plugin work's fine.
My Widget Code for Reference:
protected function getOptions(): RawJs
    {
        return RawJs::make(
            <<<JS
            {
                responsive: true,
                plugins: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        display: false,
                    },
                    description: {
                        display: false,
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: true,
                    },
                    zoom: {
                        pan: {
                            enabled: true,
                            mode: 'x',
                        },
                        zoom: {
                            wheel: {
                                enabled: true,
                            },
                            drag: {
                                enabled: false,
                            },
                            pinch: {
                                enabled: true,
                            },
                            mode: 'x',
                            onZoomComplete({chart}) {
                                chart.update('none');
                            }
                        }
                    },                    
                },
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        type: 'realtime',
                        realtime: {
                            delay: 2000,
                            refresh: 1000,
                            delay: 2000,
                            onRefresh: chart => {
                                console.log('Done');
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    y: {
                        type: 'linear',
                        display: true,
                        position: 'left',
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        max: 200,
                    },
                },

            }
            JS
        );
    }

